# Proj Error when trying to save data in PostGIS database from geodjango

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, gdal, proj, geodjango

I want to store my raster image(tiff) in my PostGIS database I have a Django model ndvitime and I want to store my tiff image from earth engine to my database. The error arises when I want to save the raster image in the database I am being using Django for this task Error is like GDAL_ERROR 1: b'PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: publication_date at the end it shows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'srid' But when I try to get projection using gdal its working Even this is Giving GeoTransform

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster, SpatialReference
landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT').filterDate(startdate,enddate).filterBounds(geometry) 
landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT').filterDate(startdate,enddate).filterBounds(geometry) 
        # Get list of images which correspond with the above
images = [item.get('id') for item in landsat.getInfo().get
for image in images:
    im = ee.Image(image).clip(geometry)
    image_props = geemap.image_props(im)
    info = (image_props.getInfo())
    date = info['DATE_ACQUIRED']
    if date not in date_acq:
        print(date)
        ndviraw = im.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4'])
        out_dir = os.getcwd()
        filename = os.path.join(out_dir, 'ndvi1.tif')
        geemap.ee_export_image(ndviraw, filename=filename, scale=30, region=roi, 
        file_per_band=False)
        rast = GDALRaster('ndvi1.tif', write=True)
        print(rast.geotransform)
        # ds = gdal.Open('ndvi1.tif')
        # in_band = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
        # print(ds.GetProjection())
        # ndvitime.objects.create(rast=in_band, name=name, date = date)
        topography = ndvitime(name=name, rast=rast, date = date)
        topography.save()
```

Comment: You have a version conflict in your system between the Proj library version and proj.db database file. Your proj version wants to read data from a column that does not exist in the corresponding tabe in proj.db database. You may have the right proj.db in your system when it would be enough to set PROJ_LIB environment to point to correct place. Similar problems https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=proj%20no%20such%20column.

Comment: When I check the program is using the PROJ_LIB inside the environment variable of Conda. And my system is using PROJ_LIB of PostgreSQL 12. Where to change. I am quite a beginner can you please help me.